# Allow parameters for parametrized queries in Data Explorer's URLs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, hyperlinks

It would be nice if you could specify parameters for parametrized queries directly in URLs.
Something like this:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/75/my-comments?UserId=1431

Comment: status-approved :)

Comment: @waffles: If you want `[status-completed]` put into the tags, flag the question for mod attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding answer so this q can be removed from Unanswered list.

Comment: Voting so the question can properly be removed from the Unanswered list.